# How can I use the linq to check if the value is NULL

Tags: c#, linq

I need to check using Linq if I have the same number of times in the database for the ZPZ_Von column and ZPZ_Bis for the same date.

I thought I did it this way, but still after setting up a breik point it appears to me in 4 values. Please correct me where I make a mistake.

```
var ZPZ_VON = from n in arrivals where n.ZPZ_Von != null select n;
var ZPZ_BIS = from n in arrivals where n.ZPZ_Bis != null select n;
```

Data like this in the database look like this.

[image]

Comment: If it is coming from a database then try DB.Null.

Comment: Do you want 2 lists of objects, one where ZPZ_Von is null and the other where ZPZ_Bis is null?

Comment: Can you do a `var list = ZPZ_VON.ToList();` and inspect the "VON" values? What is the value for the third item?

Comment: I just want to make a condition for having the same number of values ZPZ_VON and ZPZ_Bis, if NULL is to present an error, in this case, I would have had a mistake 3 ZPZ_Von and 4 ZPZ_Bis

Comment: Try this: `var ZPZ_VON = n.Where(x => x.ZPZ_Von != null || x.ZPZ_Von != default(DateTime)).ToList();`, same for ZPZ_BIS, just replace Von with Bis. And if this doesn't work, try what Hans Keﬆing suggested

Comment: Hello @MindSwipe this is helped me             var ZPZ_VON = arrivals.Where(x => x.ZPZ_Von.TimeOfDay == null || x.ZPZ_Von != default(DateTime)).ToList();
            var ZPZ_BIS = arrivals.Where(x => x.ZPZ_Bis.TimeOfDay == null || x.ZPZ_Bis != default(DateTime)).ToList();

Comment: Please note that I mistakenly wrote `x.ZPZ_Bis == null` I wasn't thinking straight, it should be `x.ZPZ_Bis != null`, besides the point of it being superfluous as DateTime can never be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because DateTime is a struct, it cannot be null. So comparing the values to null is useless, because they will never be null, but you can however compare them to the `default()` of the DateTime struct, as they might be that.

I'll be using Lambda Expressions instead of Query Expressions, as I just like them more and they're C# code instead of pseudo-sql

```cs
ZPZ_VON = n.Where(x => x.ZPZ_Von != default(DateTime)).ToList();
ZPZ_BIS = n.Where(x => x.ZPZ_Bis != default(DateTime)).ToList();
```

Note: I removed the `x.ZPZ_VON != null` I had in my comment as it is superfluous and I'd edit comment but it has been more than 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide your model but I suspect you have the `ZPZ_Von` setup as a `DateTime`.

Based off the OP the proper setup would be to have `ZPZ_Von` as a nullable: `DateTime?`

```
public class Arrival
{ 
    public DateTime? ZPZ_Von { get; set;}
}
```

And you can then check for null in your query like this:

```
n.Where(x => x.ZPZ_Von.HasValue).ToList();
```

In short, this makes your model reflect the actual db setup and will save you headaches in the long run.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this

```
var ZPZ_VON = from n in arrivals where n.ZPZ_Von is not null select n;
var ZPZ_BIS = from n in arrivals where n.ZPZ_Bis is not null select n;
```